# Why does Nintegrate keep unevaluated?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

It's no surprise that the `"MonteCarlo"` `Method` works well:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
(*1.50189*)
```

But when I try to change `"MaxPoints"`, `NIntegrate` directly refuses me.

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^5}]
```

So sad! What's the story?

Comment: Note that `NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo"}]` returns unevaluated, too.

Comment: I believe that mma  regards {"MonteCarlo"} as "MonteCarlo",but it doesn't.

Comment: I think they should be equivalent.  I think there must be some sort of bug.  When I try to `Trace` with `TraceInternal -> True`, it gobbles up memory and I have to kill it.

Comment: Bug report filed, thanks for reporting this issue!

Comment: Fixed in version 10.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if this is a bug that appears when using regions and `{"MonteCarlo"}` as a method. It hangs my machine. This might be a possible workaround:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0,0},{1,2},{2,1}}],
 Method-> "MonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 10^5}]
```

There isn't mention of the new arbitrary region functionality with the "MaxPoints" option or "MonteCarloRule" option in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#430697921). You could also convert an arbitrary region with `Boole[RegionMember[...]]` and specify some ranges for x and y. This works on my machine:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[RegionMember[
  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}],{x, y}]],
 {x,-10,10}, {y,-10,10}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.2.

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}],     
         Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^5}]                         

(* 1.49258 *)
```