# What's wrong with NIntegrate with "MonteCarlo" Method?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, random

**Bug fixed in version 10.2.0**

---

My code is:

```
NIntegrate[1, 
 x ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13), {x}], 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

Something wrong happens:

---

```
Block::lvsym: "Local variable specification {NIntegrate`XR[1]} contains NIntegrate`XR[1], which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol."
```

Comment: My related bug post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83069/why-does-nintegrate-keep-unevaluated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
NIntegrate[1,
{x} ∈ ImplicitRegion[(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13), x],
Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

The `{x}` has moved out in front. Alternatively you can do:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13)], {x, 5, 13}, 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

Also, if you want any more control over the Monte Carlo, you need to generate the random numbers yourself. This example uses the Quasi-Random Sobol generator in the MKL library provided you have it on your system (see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html) ) to produce [low-discrepancy quasi-random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Monte_Carlo_method) :

```
support = {0, 20}; (* we generate quasi randoms over the support *)
supLen = #[[2]] - #[[1]] &@support;
n = 10000;
randoms = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[Method -> {"MKL",Method -> {"Sobol",
 "Dimension" -> 1}}]; RandomReal[support, n]];
supLen * Mean[Function[{x},
    Boole[(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13)]
 ] /@ randoms]
```

Other methods available are the Mersenne Twister, Niederreiter etc.

Comment: If you're going to use low-discrepancy sequences anyway, `NIntegrate[]` does take a `"QuasiMonteCarlo"` setting…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Ahh right thanks, I just read the [ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) . Incidentally I was looking at the Classify function's SVM and it seems documentation is missing all over the place for the Method while things like NIntegrate look more fleshed out.

Comment: I have another related problem,can you help me?http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83069/why-does-nintegrate-keep-unevaluated

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed as of version 10.2.0.

```
NIntegrate[1, x ∈ ImplicitRegion[(x > 5 && x < 9) || (x > 11 && x < 13), {x}],
         Method -> "MonteCarlo"]

(* 6.06192 *)
```

The syntax is fine, since `x` is taken to be a vector variable, similarly to `NIntegrate[1, x ∈ Ball[]]`