# ParametricNDSolve without initial condition?

Tags: differential-equations

For example,

```
ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t]}, y, t, {a}]
```

returns a `ParametricFunction` which is actually inexplicable:

[image: strange ParametricFunction]

How to understand it?

Edited:
It should be noticed that it differs from

```
ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
y[1] /. sol
```

since

```
ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t]}, y, t, {a}]
y[1] /. sol
```

returns warning messages:

1. ParametricNDSolve::ndlim: Range
   specification t is not of the form {x, xend} or {x, xmin, xmax}.
2. ParametricNDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (0) (initial
       conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the
       system plus the number of discrete variables (1).

   **I wonder why ParametricNDSolve runs on though there isn't any initial conditions or boundary conditions.**

Comment: To start understanding it: what happens if you try evaluating it?

Comment: @J. M. Thank you for your attention! I don't know how to use it correctly.

Comment: So, try something like `ytest = y[1] /. sol`, and then maybe try `ytest[0]`.

Comment: But [help](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) shows how to use the result? The examples all show how to use it. Is the question about how to use the result or something else?

Comment: @Nasser, well, there is the strange part of not having an initial condition for the differential equation specified; still, you'd wonder why OP just didn't try it out for himself.

Comment: @ilian Is there something wrong?

Comment: @Wate, did you already try my suggestion?

Comment: @J. M. I have tried it but meet warnings and I have improved my question together with these warnings.

Comment: There you go! So in fact *Mathematica* knows that the data you gave it is insufficient!

Comment: @WateSoyan I don't think there is anything wrong; the `ParametricFunction` object is constructed without actually solving the equation. Once we try to evaluate it for a numeric value of the parameter `a`, we see that there is an insufficient number of initial conditions.

Comment: @ilian I think that mma should prints error message before I evaluate it for a numeric value of the parameter.In fact,I don't know what should I say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParametricNDSolve` is a *numerical* solver. You need to give it **enough numerical values** for the parameters and domain that the solver can come up with a **unique** `InterpolatingFunction` representing the numerical solution of your equation.

First, your differential equation of course has a family of $y(t)$ functions as solutions. How can ParametricNDSolve choose one among those? You need to give the numerical solver **boundary conditions**. In this case I chose `y[0] == 1` arbitrarily.

Similarly, you need to specify over which **interval** of the independent variable you would like a solution.

Putting those together:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

Let us now choose an explicit value for the parameter $a$, e.g. $0.3$:

```
yinstance = y[0.3] /. sol
```

This returns:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can plot this `InterpolatingFunction`, with $t$ ranging over the $(0,10)$ interval as specified in the call to the solver:

```
Plot[yinstance[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Aw, I was hoping the OP would try the experiment himself of trying to evaluate a `ParametricFunction[]` sans initial conditions… :D (+1 nevertheless)

Comment: Sorry.I have posted my comparison between that with initial conditions or boundary conditions and that without them.But I wonder why ParametricNDSolve runs on though there isn't any initial conditions or boundary conditions...

Comment: @J. M. oopsie! and here I come, like the proverbial bull in the china shop, and spoil all the fun! :-) I'll have to be honest though: those error messages are really not the most illuminating, and they have driven me up the wall a few times as well...

Comment: @WateSoyan I think that the catch is that no evaluation is actually attempted until you "force" it, e.g. by asking for a value etc. Having said that, I wholeheartedly agree with you there: it could fail A LOT more gracefully than that. I guess this is one more example of what I have seen the pro's refer to as *Mathematica*'s "late to fail" philosophy.

Comment: @WateSoyan I guess that in a way it is a kind attitude from the software's standpoint. It won't fail and throw up on you until it's really sure that you are without hope ;-)

Comment: What's meaning of " proverbial bull in the china shop ".i am not an English speaker.

Comment: At least OP tried it now; I wanted to impress the attitude that sometimes, you can answer your own questions just by trying. :) Judging from the OP's edit, I'd say the second error message seems appropriate: "hey, you're missing exactly one condition!"

Comment: @WateSoyan It means that I walked in and stomped all over GuessWhoItIs 's plan, like a bull, a clumsy aggressive animal, would do in a shop full of fragile porcelain items

Comment: OK,I got it.(about " proverbial bull in the china shop ")

Comment: @J. M. Should I regard it as a synatx error like this one?http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83070/whats-wrong-with-nintegrate-with-montecarlo-method